# Using Dijkstra's Algorithm with the Lemon Graph Library

Tags: c++, dijkstra, lemon-graph-library

I have a question regarding some of the parameters necessary to run Dijkstra's algorithm from the Lemon Graph Libraries (Lemon's Dijkstra's http://lemon.cs.elte.hu/pub/tutorial/a00009.html).
To run the algorithm, one would write something like `dijkstra(g, length).distMap(dist).run(s,t);` where `g` is the graph, `s` is that starting node and `t` is the destination node. My question is what is `length` and `dist`, and how are they used.
Thanks!

Comment: [one](http://lemon.cs.elte.hu/pipermail/lemon-user/2011-January/000324.html) and [two](http://lemon.cs.elte.hu/pub/doc/1.1.1/a00087.html#a58fc0895a271a1aa712f66aaf3425b12)

Comment: So to store data at each node I use a `NodeMap`? and to store the weights/distances at each arc, I use an `ArcMap`? If so, the weights will be stored in `length`, and I do not see a need for `dist`. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

The way I read it, they both need to be maps, one to edge lengths (input)
one to vertex distances(output),

Also check lgf_demo.cc and dijkstra_test.cc 
and note

> Dijkstra& distMap     (   DistMap &   m    )      [inline]
>
> Sets the map that stores the distances of the nodes calculated by the
>   algorithm. If you don't use this function before calling run() or
>   init(), an instance will be allocated automatically. The destructor
>   deallocates this automatically allocated map, of course.
>
> Returns:
>       (*this)
>
> ---
>
> const DistMap& distMap    ( )     const [inline]
>
> Returns a const reference to the node map that stores the distances of
>   the nodes calculated by the algorithm.
>
> Precondition:
>       Either run() or init() must be called before using this function.

so this is your output of Dijstra.